# Java textfield is only sometimes taking input

Tags: java, swing

I have made a simple program using Java GUI and Swing library. The user inputs "JUMP" in the text box and the button sort of "jumps" up and comes back to its original position. The problem is that it alternately takes the input and shows the correct output, even when the input is right. This the code...

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class Jump_Button extends Thread 
{
    JFrame w=new JFrame();
    JButton b=new JButton();
    JTextField t=new JTextField();
    int j=250;
    Jump_Button()
    {
        w.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        w.setLayout(null);
        w.setSize(500, 500);
        w.setVisible(true);
        w.add(t);
        w.add(b);

    b.setBounds(j, 250, 50,50);

    t.setBounds(400,400,50,50);

}
public void run()
{
    String s="";
    t.setText("");
    while(true)
    {

        try
        {
            s=t.getText();
        }
        catch(Exception e){}
        try{sleep(1000);}catch(Exception e){}

        if(s.equals(""))
        {
            j=250;
            b.setBounds(250, j, 50,50);
            try{sleep(100);}catch(Exception e){}
        }
        else if(s.equals("JUMP"))
        {
            b.setBounds(250, j-150, 50,50);
            try{sleep(1000);}catch(Exception e){}

            b.setBounds(250, j, 50,50);
            t.setText("ABC");
            try{sleep(1000);}catch(Exception e){}
            t.setText("");
        }
        else
        {
            t.setText("");
        }
    }


}
public static void main(String args[])
{
    new Jump_Button().start();
}

}
```

Comment: Maybe you should put some printStackTraces into those exceptions to make sure nothing is going wrong, just a thought. Also, what is your IO for this? examples?

Comment: Basic IO....JUMP

Answer (score 2):

you are using a separate Thread to evaluate the content of your TextField.
So things go wrong when you type JUMP, but this may be because your thread is absolutely not at the expected stage of execution (this is due to task scheduling)

You should get some documentation concerning the Listeners in Java. The Listener concept is maybe closer to the behavior you are looking for.

**It all depends on the exact expected behavior.**
*i.e. I guess you want to perform the "jump" each time the TextField contains JUMP, no matter, what, no waiting etc... And once it has jumped, clear the text field.*

Answer (score 0):

> The problem is that it alternately takes the input and shows the
>   correct output even when the input is right.

It works alternately because you are resetting the text to "" in the text field.

Get rid of the following two statements from the `else if` block for `JUMP`.

```
try{sleep(1000);}catch(Exception e){}
t.setText("");
```

Comment: It some what worked...first two time i entered -no result.After that almost after running 15 times(gave positive result) the program gave a wrong output.

Comment: Also, get rid of your `else` block. The problem is that when your thread wakes up, you might have not typed the whole text "jump". So it would reset the text in this `else` block. Just get rid of it.

Comment: Yes that worked,Thank You.Having else gives the same problem but the program is unable to check the incorrect input like "jump" etc and wipe the text field clean and wait for user to put the correct input.

Comment: @Binary_Mode, so what's the new problem you are facing after deleting the unnecessary `setText(""):` statements?

Comment: The same problem....and also as the only valid input is JUMP i need to check for other values.But I cant as adding an else block with setText("") ; creates the same problem all over again.

Comment: I changed t.setText("");  to t.setText("flag1"); and added an  else block too with t.setText("flag2");On running I found out if the program prints flag1 in the text field then immediately after it shows flag2 when the input is valid.also even when the input is valid it SOMETIMES ARBITRALLIY goes to the else part and prints flag2(Which it should not).